# Issue in graph construction

Tags: time-series, matlab, stochastic-processes, markov-process, fuzzy

I have a symbolic representation of time series obtained from [SAX toolbox](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/SAX.htm). I was wondering if it is possible to construct a graph where each node represents a unique symbol and the edges represent the transition providing that there is no transition to itself. For ex, let the time series T of n=20 data points be represented as
 `T=[1 1 2 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 3 3 1]'` where number of alphabets used to symbolize = 3 and they are (1,2,3). I have combined co-occuring symbols together so, the compressed time series becomes

```
T' = [1 2 1 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1]'
```

In order to construct a graph (Esp. [fuzzy cognitive map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_cognitive_map) ) with fuzzy membership values from T' where the nodes will be (1,2,3), there will be an edge from $Node_i$ to $Node_j$ and it will have a weight $W_{ji}$. How do I find the weights ? I do not know which theory to search for this kind of problem and so if there are any ideas as to what can form the weights. Thank you

Comment: I don't think you've clearly defined the weight, but I'm guessing it's the number of times $j$ followed $i$. And perhaps you meant $W_{ij}$. If I'm right, then maybe you're just looking for a first order Markov model. More useful terms might be stochastic matrix and transition matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but my example is more inclined towards constructing a fuzzy cognitive map where the nodes represent s0me actions or states and the weights are fuzzy. Your idea of defining weight is really great. SO, how do I construct a first order Markov model? I had read about it but never really understood the meaning of "hidden states" etc.

Comment: Seeing "hidden," I'm wondering if you stumbled upon hidden Markov models. What I was referring to was a "Markov model" represented as a stochastic matrix where the probability of transition from state $i$ to state $j$ (represented as nodes, if you want) is equal to the weight of the "link" pointing from $i$ to $j$, or the matrix location $X_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in R. Note, I have used your original data with self-transitions (non-transitions) included. You can do the same thing with the "compressed time series," however.

Say I have already constructed an edge list from your example data in the form of the following matrix

```
el <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3), .Dim = c(8L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
c("i", "j", "w")))
el
#     i j w
#[1,] 1 1 4
#[2,] 2 1 2
#[3,] 3 1 3
#[4,] 1 2 4
#[5,] 2 2 1
#[6,] 1 3 1
#[7,] 2 3 2
#[8,] 3 3 3
```

It captures the facts that state $1$ followed state $1$ (i.e., no transition) four times, state $1$ followed state $2$ twice, and so on. I now capture this same information in the form of a square $3 \times 3$ matrix.

```
X <- matrix(0,3,3)
X[el[,1:2]]<-el[,3]
X
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    4    1
#[2,]    2    1    2
#[3,]    3    0    3
```

Now I want the elements to represent proportions with respect to the rest of the elements in their own row only. That is, rows should sum to $1$ meaning that in every state there will be some transition with probability $1$ and the individual elements of the row capture the distribution of that probability across all possible next states.

```
X <- X / rowSums(X)
X
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.4444444 0.4444444 0.1111111
#[2,] 0.4000000 0.2000000 0.4000000
#[3,] 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
```

These proportions can be taken as the transition probabilities. Here we see that the probability of transitioning from state $1$ to state $3$ is found at location $X_{13}$ and is equal to $0.11$. This is to say that of all the observations of the system being in state $1$ ($9$ times not counting the last one that offered no information about transition), in approximately $11\%$ of them (once) the process transitioned to state $3$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply & apologies for my delay.I have few questions & shall be glad for clarification (A)In the first table, 1 is followed by 3 times right?Same for 2-1 is once?(B) I did not quite understand the third table construction -how the probabilities are assigned?

Comment: @SKM 
 
In the second table, the 4 in the first row, second column represents the number of times the value 2 followed the value 1 in the original data series. The corresponding probability in the third table is calculated as the elements value (4) divided by the sum across the whole row (4+4+1=11). Thus, 44% of the time a 1 appears in the series, a 2 follows it.